# To clear loaded images in a picturebox-c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Initially I will be loading images(say 20 images) into a picturebox from a specified folder through selection from combobox dropdown, they get loaded normally into the picturebox.

The problem I am facing is when I select the next folder to acquire the image for processing, the previously selected folders images are also displayed in the picturebox after its count only the next folders images are displayed, I am unable to clear the previously loaded images.

To be specific, when I click on a folder from dropdown I want the particular folders image inside the picturebox I don't want the previously loaded images along with them. Am working in VS2013 with c#.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        int filelength = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new      DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\scanned");
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories();
            comboBox1.DataSource = folders;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i + 1 < filelength)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i + 1].ToString());
                i = i + 1;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (i - 1 >= 0)
            {

                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i - 1].ToString());
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                i = i - 1;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\scanned", selected);
            DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders1 = di1.GetDirectories();
            comboBox2.DataSource = folders1;

        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string selected1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string selected2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

                        //Initially load all your image files into the array list when form load first time
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo inputDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\scanned", selected1, selected2)); //Source image folder path


            try
            {


                if ((inputDir.Exists))
                {

                    //Get Each files 
                    System.IO.FileInfo file = null;
                    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo eachfile in inputDir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        file = eachfile;
                        if (file.Extension == ".tif")
                        {
                            alist.Add(file.FullName); //Add it in array list
                            filelength = filelength + 1;
                        }
                        else if(file.Extension == ".jpg")
                        {

                            alist.Add(file.FullName); //Add it in array list
                            filelength = filelength + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[0].ToString());  //Display intially first image in picture box as sero index file path
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    i = 0;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                if (i + 1 < filelength)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i + 1].ToString());
                    i = i + 1;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                }
            }
            else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                if (i - 1 >= 0)
                {

                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i - 1].ToString());
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    i = i - 1;
                }
            }
        }


        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], please read [ask] and show us what have you tried

Comment: From my brief google searching, here is a suggestion. Try `pictureBox.Image = null;` before loading the new images.

Comment: it is not workingout with picturebox1.image=null; @KeyurPATEL

Comment: `PictureBox1.Image = null` is correct, your code there is all lower case and the C# Language is case sensitive.

Comment: As @SimonPrice said, make sure you added the right line, case sensitive, also try `pictureBox.Image = null; pictureBox.Invalidate();`. Invalidate causes the picturebox to repaint.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the memory or cache, loaded images are not getting cleared and have tried most possible ways. How to clear the memory of the loaded images when clicking the button again @KeyurPATEL

Comment: How about clearing your alist, since its the source of your images. `ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();` again or `alist.Clear();`.

Comment: thank you so much mr. @TaW  it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @Keyur PATEL it worked for me using alist.clear(); by specifying filelength = alist.Count; after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has **many** issues.

The one you are looking for is that you don't clear the `alist` before loading new file names.

So insert:

```
    alist.Clear();
```

before

```
    //Get Each files
```

And also

```
   filelength = alist.Count;
```

after the loop. No need to count while adding!

Also note that `ArrayList` is pretty much depracated and you should use the type-safe and powerful  `List<T>` instead:

```
List<string> alist = new List<string>();
```

Of course a class variable named `i` is silly and you are also relying on always having a `SelectedItem` in the comboBox2.

And since you are not properly Disposing of the Image you are leaking GDI resources.

You can use this function for properly loading images:

```
void loadImage(PictureBox pbox, string file)
{
    if (pbox.Image != null)
    {
        var dummy = pbox.Image;
        pbox.Image = null;
        dummy.Dispose();
    }
    if (File.Exists(file)) pbox.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
}
```

It first creates a reference to the `Image`, then clears the `PictureBox`'s reference, then uses the reference to `Dispose` of the `Image` and finally tries to load the new one.