# WinForms PictureBox: Trying to display a photo from a file path

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

What I am trying to do feels pretty straight forward, however it continuously throws an error when attempting.

Goal: I am teaching myself C#, and to do so I am building my own SW5E Character Builder cause why not. What I am trying to do currently is when you click on a species, it will display the Species Info in a RichTextBox, and a photo of the species in a PictureBox.

Issue: I can get the Rich Text to display just fine, but when I attempt to load an image in it throws an Out of Memory Error every time.

My Code is as follows:

```
private void SpeciesList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Here we save the selected list item
            string selectedSpecies = SpeciesList.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;

            // We are saving that selection for later
            _selectedSpecies = selectedSpecies;

            // Loading the information in the rich text document just fine
            SpeciesInfoRichTxt.LoadFile($@"D:\repos\Character Builder\Species\{selectedSpecies}\{selectedSpecies}.rtf");

            // This is where we run into issues, as this just throws an Out of Memory error each time
            // It doesn't even have a default image set, the box itself is blank
            SpeciesPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile($@"D:\repos\Character Builder\Species\{selectedSpecies}\{selectedSpecies}.jpg");
        }
```

I am not 00% sure where I am going wrong. I have tested this code on several different computers, hence why the file path is pointing to D: at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a default image already loaded in the PictureBox?  If so, that needs to be `Dispose`d of before you try to put another one in there.

Comment: The issue was not in the code, but correct disposal is still important.                        [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754206/error-when-im-trying-to-delete-an-image-used-in-a-picturebox/57754802#57754802) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483712/to-clear-loaded-images-in-a-picturebox-c/39487494#39487494) an example for correctly loading fresh images..

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. It wasn't that I wasn't Disposing an image (I did add `SpeciesPictureBox.Image?.Dispose();` and that did not change the outcome. When I initially saved the file, I ended up changing the extension from whatever it was trying to save as by default to .jpg, completely not thinking it would break the file. When I went back and saved it, then used Paint to Save As a .jpg, then Image.FromFile stopped throwing the error and worked.

I guess if you are running into the same issue as I am, make sure that you are not just changing file extensions when moving the image where you need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).